# usestate not setting the data

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

i am using usestate for transfer data. but ufotunately it not quite work.

here is my code:

```
const [totCons, settotCons] = useState(null)
     useEffect(() => {
        // declare the async data fetching function
        const fetchData = async () => {
          // get the data from the api
          const data = await fetch('https://piscons2.vercel.app/ConsPiscTotCons');
          // convert the data to json
          const json = await data.json();       
          // set state with the result
          settotCons(json);
          console.log(json)
          console.log(totCons)
        }  
        // call the function
        fetchData()
          // make sure to catch any error
          .catch(console.error);;
      }, [])
```

as you can see on image the json return data but the totCons return null.
i did set it `settotCons(json)`

[image]

Comment: This comes up _every day_, and I do not understand why. **Where do you think you assigned to `totCons`?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 2):

Updated state will not be available to the state value immedieately.

The react `setState` is asynchronous, but thats not the only reason for this behaviour.  The reason is a closure scope around an immutable const value.

Both props and state [are assumed to be unchanging during 1 render.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

> Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

You can use `useEffect` to create the sideeffects for `totCons`

```
useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of totCons
}, [totCons]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing console.log(totCons) outside useEffect.
you will not get the updated value in next line.
you will get the updated value in next render